# What's the word for "changing the discussion level/style"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine two people talking about politics, using rational arguments and philosophical theories, and suddenly a third one comes in and starts ranting about the same topic, but from a very subjective perspective.

Or else, someone posts a humorous, yet shallow picture on facebook, related to recent events, and someone else comments, but in a highly elaborated manner.

In general, a discussion could be led for example in an academic way, it could be pub talk, it could be over-emotionalised, childlike, silly, precocious, relaxed, it could be in the style of a BBC interview or a heated quarrel. I would call all these "discussion styles" in lack of a better term.

*What is a word (or an expression) for changing the discussion style or conversation level in such a way? Or is there even a better word for "discussion style"?*
In particular, I'm looking for a technical term possibly used by linguists.

An example sentence for the first question might be "In facebook conversations between people of different educational levels, [?] are frequently observed.", and for the second question "Alice and Bob were discussing politics when suddenly Charlie came in and completely changed the [...]"

Note that I'm not looking for an [idiom for changing the subject in a conversation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240535/idiom-expression-for-changing-the-subject-in-a-conversation). The subject should stay the same, only the way the conversation is led should change.

I am also not looking for a specific way how the discussion changed, like "escalation".

Comment: "change the debate" refers to style, arguments or approach rather than the subject of the conversation.

Comment: "change the depth of the discussion" ?

Comment: *change the nature of the discussion*, *the discussion's course got altered* ?

Comment: I think "hijack the discussion" is accurate, as long as the context  differentiates it from a complete change of subject. "We were having a level-headed discussion about the election when (person) *hijacked the discussion* to rant about (candidate)". In other situations, I might use the term "escalate".

Comment: @BradC escalate is nice, though obviously only works in one direction

Comment: The opposite of a discussion "escalating" would be a discussion *descending (or devolving) into chaos* or perhaps "dissolving into an argument". You could also say a discussion "became heated". These are all detailed descriptions of exactly *how* the discussion changed, though, not a general term for a change in demeanor.

Answer (score 1):

**Change of tone**, e.g. quoting [The Times](http://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/turning-point-will-change-the-tone-of-debate-b26kbz6s8) newspaper

> Turning point **will change the tone of debate** [...] 
>   The death of an MP [Joe Cox 1974-2016] less than a week from the EU referendum has already had a profound effect on the course of the campaign

A definition of **Tone**:

> 4. Manner of expression in speech or writing: *took an angry **tone** with the reporters.*
>
> 5. A general quality, effect, or atmosphere: *a room with an elegant **tone**.*
>
> — [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tone)

Comment: The _tone_ of a debate seems to me to be mainly related to the emotional content of the debate.

Answer (score 1):

**Divergence:**

[*A feature of speech in linguistics*] When the register and stylistic aspects of the speaker becomes apparently different and incongruent during the course of a conversation.

The individual in this case would adjust his speech patterns to be distinct from those of other individuals belonging to another group/social identity.

*Divergence here can be understood as transient and individual/perosnal phenomena, as it is characterised by a creative choice deliberately made by the individual to reflect/represent his/her feelings in a given situation, at a given time.

[Note that, in other occasions, the same person may make an opposite or different choice freely, for quite logical reasons].

Discussion style= discourse style, speech style

Comment: So divergence occurs in a single speaker, and not in the relation between the discourse style of one speaker to the style of another?